# Mirror downloads with PHP

Tags: php

Let's say i have a main site with a file to download, like :

```
www.mysite.com/download.zip
```

I have another domain :

```
www.myothersite.com
```

I want when the person goes to www.myothersite.com/download.zip ,  it serves the same file that is on www.mysite.com/download.zip .

But i don't want to copy the same file to myothersite, i want to have only one source of download, but in different domains. Is that possible with PHP ?

I know i can achieve this by editing the htaccess file. But is there a way to achieve the same results only using PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: How are you serving files? Also why don't you want to use an htaccess?

Comment: You do realise that the point of having a mirror is that the file will be accessible even when the server that holds the original copy is down, right?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, i'm just doing some tests to try to avoid Windows Defender false positives when downloading a install package from my main site. It seems when i download the SAME file from another domain, the false positive do not happens.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'd like just to know how this could be possible using only PHP. I can use htaccess too.

Comment: That's only answering part of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with just php... In php you can do something like this:

in `www.mysite.com` you have a `download.php` file:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
  header('Location: www.myothersite.com/'. $_GET['link'].'.zip');
  exit;
 }

?>
```

So `www.mysite.com/download.php?link=download` will lead to `www.myothersite.com/download.zip`.

This is just an example I don't know which and how many files you want to make available from your website.

Another way is to use an .htaccess config file.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not linking it to the file directly?
For example, on your second website, you can put the link in the a tag directly to the file on your first website. You can also add the `download` attribute to your a tag to tell the browser it's a download.

### HTML

```
<a href="http://site1.com/download.zip" download>Download</a>
```

For more information about the download attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp